# Getting parent value(Text) by selecting child (inside nested loop).Handle duplicate child value in side another parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

>
I got a problem, My Jquery runs fine  for one selected item but when  the multiple items are selected I start getting the values of unselected child. I only wanted the Selected Parent(station_group) and Child(Unit_group) checkboxes. Please Help my Current code.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#searchButton",function() {
                var InputString="-";
                $.each($('input[name="Station_group"'),function(index,item){
                    if($(item).is('input:checked')){   
                        var StationItem =$(this).val();
                        $.each($('input[name="Unit_group"'),function(index,item){
                            if($(item).is('input:checked')){
                                var unitItem = $(this).val();                                                              
                                $.each($('input[name="Alarm_group"'),function(index,item){
                                    if($(item).is('input:checked')){
                                        var alarmItem = $(this)[0].nextSibling.nodeValue;;
                                        var resultString = StationItem.concat(","+unitItem+","+alarmItem+"|");
                                        InputString=InputString+resultString;
                                    };
                                });
                            };
                        });
                    }; 
                });
             });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of head hunting, i manage to find the answer to my own question.The logic needed to change instead of looping by parent-child. I decide to loop by selected child and then getting the parent value. Using the jquery parent and eq function I was able to find the needed values.

```
$.each($('input[name="Unit_group"'),function(index,item){
                            if($(item).is('input:checked')){
                                var unitItem = $(this).val();
                                var stationitem=$(this).parents('li').eq(1).find('input').val();
                                $.each($('input[name="Alarm_group"'),function(index,item){
                                    if($(item).is('input:checked')){
                                        var alarmItem = $(this)[0].nextSibling.nodeValue;;
                                        var resultString = stationitem.concat(","+unitItem+","+alarmItem+"|");
                                        InputString=InputString+resultString;
                                    };
                                });
                            };
```